# dependency_onchange method firing only one time when using sqlnotificationargs.info instead of sqlnotificationargs.type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, signalr, sqldependency

```
public void SendNotification()
{
    string message = "";
    string constr = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string query = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_Onchange);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                message = message + "<br>" + reader.GetSqlValue(0);
                notifications_count = notifications_count + 1;
                _IsUnread = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void dependency_Onchange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
     SendNotification();
    }

}
```

so the above code is working fine(firing every time) when using  `if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)` but the the problem is when I am using this  `if (e.Info.ToString() == "Insert")` inside dependency_onchange like

```
private void dependency_Onchange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        if (e.Info.ToString() == "Insert")
        {
            SendNotification();
        }
    }

}
```

the method only fires one time.

Answer (score -1):

Hey i know it might be a bit too late i had a similar problem and its very simple

You must use syntax like **[dbo].TableName where = vlaue** not just table name, and no operators like **"in"** or  *****  for sql statement.

try this...i know its silly but  i had exactly the same problem with similar code

```
e.info.ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "insert"
```

or more simple

```
e.info.ToString().Contains("Insert")
```

**If that is not the case**

Then you might have looping functions since in sql dependancy if you are trying to make notifications to specific clients you will run into a problem of splitting up the notification select , update or insert. To see if everything is working fine and something else is causing issues due to overlap add a static list and add the reader value into it to see for possible overlap.